# How to decide whether to use robust errors in 2sls estimation

Tags: econometrics, heteroscedasticity, instrumental-variables, 2sls, breusch-pagan

For my data, I have run both the OLS and IV regression to investigate the effects of health on salary. The BP test showed Heteroskedasticity for the OLS error terms so I decided to run the OLS regression using robust errors to tackle this problem. I then moved on to run the 2sls regression  and carried out the Breusch Hall test using the ivhettest demand on Stata, the results once again showed heteroskedasticity. Does it mean I will need to use robust errors for my 2sls regression as well? Therefore the command on Stata should be ivreg2 lnsalary health (education= siblings' education), vce(robust)?